# How to write an ex script that searches for text and deletes the next n lines?

Tags: vim, ex

I want to write an ex script that searches for text and then deletes 23 lines. I created an `exscript` file that contains:

```
/block_2/
23d
w
```

I then tried `$ ex - index.html < exscript`, but it makes wrong, unpredictable edits.

Those commands work when opening the file in ex, but not with the script. How can I fix it? I don't want to use line numbers, since I have to run the script on hundreds of files, and the line numbers will be different.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out:

Script:

```
g/block_2/ .,+22 d
x
```

Then:

```
$ ex - index.html < exscript
```

Comment: You can simplify that range into a count. e.g. `g/block_2/d23`